# Chrome Double Request Causing Side Effects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, http

I have encountered an issue in Chrome that causes two requests to be sent to my .Net MVC application.  I have a controller that is listening for requests and changes some application state when it receives one.  This is happening twice when a user would only expect once and so ends up with an unexpected state.

My working theory is that this is caused by a feature of Chrome called "[Instant Pages](https://chrome.googleblog.com/2011/08/instant-pages-on-google-chrome.html)" that's supposed to request pages as you type in the omni-bar but I'm not sure.

To fix this, I tried making the controller only take POST requests, but this presents new problems.  The administrator of the web site needs to be able to link to this action from places like an external site or a marketing email.  When the action accepts a POST, links like this cause errors.

Here's the controller action:

```
public ActionResult HandleMembershipRequest(
  int amount, 
  int fundID, 
  bool waiveBenefits, 
  DateTime? dateOfBirth, 
  bool? isGift, 
  bool? autoRenew)
    { \\change some application state }
```

The urls we have been using to link to the action look like: `/Membership/HandleMembershipRequest?amount=150&waiveBenefits=False&fundID=1058`

I'd like to know:

1. What's causing the issue?
2. How can I prevent the duplicate requests while also allowing links to this action?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind for preventing duplicate requests is keeping track of whether or not that request has been processed in the session state, or when it was last processed.  I don't know how often a single user would need to call that action, but you could prevent duplicates within, for example, 30 seconds of the last request.

Comment: @LukeSamuel that would work, but I think there must be a more elegant way to do this than recording actions as they come in and checking them against each other.  This would add a lot of overhead on the web server.